# How to check if javascript object is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I suspect to have a memory leak in a javascript game project that I am working on. We create a lot of projects and try to delete them when they are irrelevant. Is there a way to check whether the object is deleted and GCed (garbage collected)?

For example we might create a notification that is not assigned to a specific object:

```
//a button is pressed in some window
var notification = new someNamespace.Notification("notification text")
```

And when, for example, "OK" button is pressed the notification is closed and removed from the canvas rendering flow (we use PIXI.js). There is no clear reference to the object, so how to check if the object is really gone? Using "in" operator is useless if there is no clear context, or am I wrong here?

Comment: are you talking about garbage collection in javascript right?

Comment: In Chrome check your your 'Profiles' tab and select 'Take Heap Snapshot'. If the object is still there it is not garbage collected. In your button example do not forget to unbind the event handler.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about javascript garbage collection. Does the heap snaphots show object prototype names, I am a bit confused in the info it gives.